# Is there a way to control the width of wtf.form_field input fields without affecting the label width?

Tags: flask, jinja2, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I am currently rendering several Flask fields (SelectFields, InputFields) using the following **jinja2** template:

```
<div>{{ wtf.form_field(form.blockingProbability) }}</div>
```

This results in the following format:

[image: Current rendering]

I'd like to control the width of the dropdown list (narrower width would look more natural, methinks), but (unsurprisingly) when I try doing this by controlling the `div` width, the entire field, including the label is constrained and the label text wraps around.

Is there any way to control the width of the dropdown field (and other input fields), while keeping the width of the label intact (unwrapped)?

Comment: Can you post the code of your form class?

Comment: Are you using `flask-bootstrap`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This worked for me
jinja2 template:

```
<div style="width: 50%">
    {{ form1.language.label }}
</div>
<div style="width: 25%">
    {{ form1.language }}
</div>
```

[image]

This is the form1 class:

```
class myForm(Form):
   language = SelectField(u'Programming Language', choices=[('cpp', 'C++'), ('py', 'Python'), ('text', 'Plain Text')])
```

Comment: I was hoping to find a way to do this directly with wtf.form_field() rendering to maintain visual consistency with other fields that won't require width override, but I can live with this (just need to use the same method for all fields, even the ones at 100% width).

Comment: Also works,**{{ form1.language (style="width:25%;") }}**

Answer (score 2):

This should work too and it also maintain the visual consistency with other fields' widths:

```
<div>{{ wtf.form_field(form.blockingProbability, horizontal_columns=('lg', 2, 4)) }}</div>
```

The last value - `4` - in `horizontal_columns` sets the width of the input field.

Comment: Thanks. At least for me, this only works for form_type="horizontal" (rather than "basic"), but this might come in useful at some later stage.  `<div>{{ wtf.form_field(form.blockingProbability, form_type="horizontal", horizontal_columns=('lg', 6, 3)) }}</div>`

Answer (score 0):

When the Jinja2 code is rendered to HTML it will fill in a bunch of attributes on each form field. For your example, if you examine the page after it renders it should look something like:

```
<div>
    <label for='blockingProbability'>
        Blocking Probability
    </label>
    <input id='blockingProbability' name='blockingProbability' ... >
</div>
```

So you can control the fields and labels as a group or individually by adding some CSS into your Jinja2 template head:

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        input {
            width: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
```